# Redirect to another domain and display a non-existing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Not sure if this has been asked before as I've been searching and reading up on htaccess coding and trying it out but to no luck.

I have a domain abc.com.sg and have a php redirect script that will instantly redirect a user to abc.com. The issue is, i would like them to see that they have been redirected to abc.com/sg/, while still displaying stuff from abc.com.

I know this can be done with modrewrite of some kind.
This is some sort similar but of the same domain, mine is technically a different domain on the same server. [Redirect But Not Show The URL redirec :: htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391661/redirect-but-not-show-the-url-redirec-htaccess).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control of abc.com and the ability to set up redirects there?  If not, I don't think you can do it.  Otherwise, what's stopping me from redirecting people to google.com/mycompany, while showing them google.com's content, correct?

Comment: Yes I have access to both domains.

Comment: Does the sg part need to act as a variable that can change?

Comment: You mean the abc.com/sg/ here? As of now, no. Whenever a user goes to abc.com.sg, I will redirect them to abc.com and it will appear as abc.com/sg