# MASKING URL with HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mask

I am trying to redirect visitors of alldomain.com to the domain newdomain.com it does redirect however I want that when the user open's alldomain.com the data should be of newdomain.com however the top url should be alldomain.com

My Current HTACCESS:

RedirectMatch .* http://www.newdomain.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect But Not Show The URL redirec :: htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391661/redirect-but-not-show-the-url-redirec-htaccess)

Comment: You may find the information at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/htaccess-redirect-to-subfolder-in-different-domain-maintaining-old-domain-in-t useful. It takes a bit more than `.htaccess` to do this properly...

Comment: Floris: Iv already checked with that and that did not work. That tells about redirecting inside the main domain my concern is to redirect to another outside external domain.

Comment: Welcome to SO, WiKi.  As Floris mentioned already, this isn't really a question for SO.  Please follow his or [this link](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to this consist of two parts: correct `.htaccess`, and using `mod_proxy` on your Apache server:

Uncomment these lines in `httpd.conf` (and restart Apache!):

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Add the following lines to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine    on
RewriteRule      .*  http://www.newdomain.com/  [P]
ProxyPassReverse /   http://www.newdomain.com/
```

The key here is that the `[P]` flag in the `RewriteRule` tells Apache to use `mod_proxy` (which you enabled earlier), and the `ProxyPassReverse` makes sure that any links from the new domain are properly "attributed" to the old domain as well. I **think** that does it, but I can't test... Let me know whether this works for you!